# Determine time spent preprocessing

Tags: build, g++, gnu-make

We are tuning our build system, which is big, and uses gnu make and g++.  We'd like to run a full build and find out how much time is spent by c++  preprocessing. Can anyone suggest a strategy for doing this?

Comment: Please clarify if you are referring to the C++ preprocessor or some other preprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`g++ -ftime-report` will show an estimate of preprocessing time, like this:

```
$ yes 'int f();' | head -n 1000000 > t.c
$ g++ -ftime-report -c t.c

Execution times (seconds)
 phase setup             :   0.01 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 0%) wall    1386 kB ( 0%) ggc
 phase parsing           :   3.13 (100%) usr   2.06 (100%) sys   5.19 (100%) wall  772546 kB (100%) ggc
 |name lookup            :   0.41 (13%) usr   0.11 ( 5%) sys   0.52 (10%) wall      90 kB ( 0%) ggc
 preprocessing           :   0.46 (15%) usr   0.84 (41%) sys   1.10 (21%) wall   65548 kB ( 8%) ggc
 parser (global)         :   2.51 (80%) usr   1.19 (57%) sys   3.87 (74%) wall  706998 kB (91%) ggc
 varconst                :   0.16 ( 5%) usr   0.03 ( 1%) sys   0.22 ( 4%) wall       0 kB ( 0%) ggc
 TOTAL                 :   3.14             2.07             5.21             773943 kB
```

The line with `preprocessing` might not show up if no discernible time was spent preprocessing.